# Average electric potential over a spherical volume

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, electricity, potential

I know the average potential over a spherical **surface** equals the potential at the center of sphere.
But is it also true for average over spherical **volume** ?

In both cases the sphere is empty of charge.

Comment: More information is needed. Is the spherical surface the surface of a solid sphere or a hollow sphere? Is its material a conductor or an insulator? Is it charged?

Comment: If your sphere is centered on a point charge in space, then the claim that the average potential on the surface is equal to the potential at the center is certainly not true.

Comment: I updated the question, I'm interested in the case of sphere with no charge inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to use the mathematical terminology where a "ball" of radius $R$ centered around $P$ is the set of all points whose distance from $P$ is less than or equal to $R$, while the surface of the ball, consisting of the points with distance exactly $R$ from $P$, is a "sphere".

If a function is harmonic over a ball of radius $R$ centered around $P$, then a well-known theorem states that the average value of that function over the sphere of radius $R$ equals the value of the function at the point $P$. Note that when the electric potential in a ball is entirely due to stationary charges that lie outside the ball, then the potential within the ball is harmonic.

If we take the average of the function over the entire ball, instead of just over the sphere, then that ball can be thought of as a collection of nested spheres, and each of those spheres has an average value equal to the value at $P$. The overall average across a collection of sets that all have the same average value is just that value.

To write this down in terms of integrals is not too difficult. Without loss of generality, place $P$ at the origin. The average electric potential over the ball of radius $R$ is

$$ \overline{\varphi} = \frac{3}{4\pi R^3} \int_0^R \int_{S(r)}  \varphi \, \mathrm{d}V  $$

where $S(r)$ is the sphere of radius $r$. But $\mathrm{d}V$ is just $ \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}a$, where $\mathrm{d}a$ is the area element for the integration over $S(r)$. So we cen rewrite this as

$$ \overline{\varphi} = \frac{3}{4\pi R^3} \int_0^R \left[ \int_{S(r)} \varphi \, \mathrm{d}a \right] \mathrm{d}r $$

We know that $\frac{1}{4\pi r^2} \int_{S(r)} \varphi \, \mathrm{d}a = \varphi(0)$, as that's just the average over the sphere. So the quantity in square brackets equals $4\pi r^2 \varphi(0)$:

$$ \overline\varphi = \frac{3}{4\pi R^3} \int_0^R 4\pi r^2 \varphi(0) \, \mathrm{d}r = \varphi(0)$$